# Where are the css file of the primefaces show case "Grid CSS - responsive layout"

Tags: java, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying the fantastic worl of responsive web design with primefaces but I can't found the css file of the show case:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml

I have copied the show case but no works on my pc.
This show case is not included in the downloadable showcase sources.

http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/showcase/5.0/showcase-5.0.war

The description says "Grid CSS is a lightweight (1.4KB) responsive layout utility optimized for mobile devices, tablets and desktops."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grid CSS is a new feature available since 5.0.5 / 5.1, so you won't be able to find what you are looking for in your 5.0 archive.

See: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7215

The online showcase is actually running on PrimeFaces 5.1.2, but the latest showcase which is available to download is also running PrimeFaces 5.0

However, the CSS file your are looking for is available in the primefaces 5.1 download, located under `/META-INF/resources/primefaces/primefaces.css`

Comment: Not found on this path. Maybe, primefaces-5.1-sources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/grid/grid.css (Community Downloads)

Comment: I just checked this download: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/primefaces/primefaces/5.1/primefaces-5.1.jar (the primefaces-5.1.jar from the community downloads, not the primefaces-5.1-sources.jar)